# How can I get the FQDN of the current host in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, fqdn

I need to get the fully expanded hostname of the host that my Ruby script is running on.  In Perl I've used Sys::Hostname::Long with good results.  Google seems to suggest I should use Socket.hostname in ruby, but that's returning just the nodename, not the full hostname.

Answer (score 20):

This seems to work:

```
hostname = Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first
```

Comment: On Mac OS X this seems to return the hostname in lowercase : `$ruby -e 'puts Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first'     xin.local` in contrast to the bash 'hostname' command `$ hostname    XIN.local`

Comment: this solution is since ruby 2.7+ deprecated

Comment: and what's the new solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
hostname = Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first
```

is not recommended and will only work if your reverse DNS resolution is properly set up. [This Facter bug](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/3898) has a longer explanation if needed.

If you read the facter code, you'll notice that they somewhat [sidestep the issue altogether by saying](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/master/lib/facter/fqdn.rb):

```
fqdn = hostname + domainname
```

where:

```
hostname = %[hostname]
domainname = %[hostname -f] # minus the first element
```

This is a reasonable assumption that does not depend on the setup of DNS (which may be external to the box).

Comment: If the domain name isn't set on the machine, hostname -f will query DNS as well.

Answer (score -5):

Could be a tad simpler =>  hostname = Socket.gethostname

Comment: Socket.gethostname doesn't necessarily return a FQDN.