# Execute a linux command using ruby for getting hostname

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby .

I have to write def , which returns the value by executing the command 'hostname -f' in a linux server. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Instead of using hostname -f, you may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151545/how-can-i-get-the-fqdn-of-the-current-host-in-ruby) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the command within backticks.  Use the chomp method to remove any trailing newline.

```
def get_host
  `hostname -f`.chomp
end
```