# What is the proper way to get FQDN of current host?

Tags: ruby, deprecated, hostname, rubocop, fqdn

For some time I was using code:

```
hostname = Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151545/how-can-i-get-the-fqdn-of-the-current-host-in-ruby).

But, as the comment said - it's deprecated, and now both rubocop and ruby itself are complaining:

```
=$ ./z.rb 
./z.rb:5: warning: Socket.gethostbyname is deprecated; use Addrinfo.getaddrinfo instead.

=$ rubocop z.rb
...
z.rb:5:13: W: Lint/DeprecatedClassMethods: Socket.gethostbyname is deprecated in favor of Addrinfo#getaddrinfo.
puts Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use getaddrinfo to get the same information. Anyone could show an example?

For now, I figured I'll just use:

```
`hostname --fqdn`
```

which works, as I only run it on Linux, but it's not really nice approach.

Comment: `hostname` also does not consistently work on macOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got help in some other way, but figured others might benefit too.

Current way to do it is:

```
require 'socket'
Addrinfo.getaddrinfo(Socket.gethostname, nil).first.getnameinfo.first
```